# Pivot in sqlserver with null values

Tags: sql-server

i have this data in my table.

```
create table #school
(
  id int ,
  [type] varchar(50),
  student bit ,
  teacher bit,
  principal bit
)

 insert into #school 
 (
   id,
  [type] ,
  student 
 )values
(1, 'Student',1)

insert into #school 
(
  id,
  [type] ,
  teacher 
 )values
(1, 'Teacher',0)

 insert into #school 
(
  id,
  [type] ,
  principal  
  )values
(1, 'Principal',0)

select * from #school
```

How Can I get the above data in below format ?

```
  id   student  teacher  principal
   1     1        0       0
```

I am trying with pivot option in sql query but i am not getting what exactly look like above

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

If there can be multiple entries for a type ie. then:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Student,0) AS INT)) AS Student,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Teacher,0) AS INT)) AS Teacher, 
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Principal,0) AS INT)) AS Principal
FROM 
    #school 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

This assumes that you only want to count the TRUE values, else use a simpler count version as provided earlier.

By using ISNULL([fld],0) every record now has a value, and thus the sum() function will now count all the TRUE results being that the CAST() function converts them to a countable INT data type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what purpose the `[type]` column is serving here, or why you think you need to pivot

You can achieve the above with [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177673.aspx)

E.g.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(student) as student, COUNT(teacher) as teacher, COUNT(principal) as principal
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

MAX Condition won't work when Student, Teacher are bit datatypes

```
 select ID,
      max(case when Type = 'Student' then Student end) Car,
      max(case when Type = 'Teacher' then Teacher end) Truck,
      max(case when Type = 'Principal' then Principal end) Bicycle
    from #school
    GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this result as you've got the Type specified in columns:

select id, max(cast(student as int)) as student, max(cast(teacher as int)) as teacher, max(cast(principal as int )) as principal from #school group by id

If you need to return the values as bit have to cast them once again as bit.